# How to unit test TweenMax? Potential mock?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I am attempting to unit test my function that uses **TweenMax** from **GSAP**, but I am unsure of how best to go about it...

```
@ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: ElementRef;
expanded = false;

toggleDropdown() {
    const dropdown = this.dropdown.nativeElement;

    TweenMax.to(dropdown, 0.5, {
      css: {
        height: this.expanded ? '34px' : '376px'
      },
      ease: Power2.easeInOut,
    });

    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
```

I was thinking of potentially mocking TweenMax, but the attempt I have made received the error:

> Expected a spy, but got Object({ to: spy on unknown.to }).

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockTween = createSpyObj(['to']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [...],
      declarations: [...],
      providers: [... ,
        {provide: TweenMax, useValue: mockTween}
      ]
    });

    ...
  }));

it('should set dropdown height to 376px if not currently expanded', () => {
    component.expanded = false;

    component.toggleDropdown();

    expect(mockTween).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I deleted my previous answer because it was getting long.

Following the stackblitz you provided, I have also created one myself :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jasmine-tween-j5wsz9?file=app/tween/tween.component.spec.ts

As you can see, it works like a charm.

```
fdescribe('TweenComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TweenComponent>, component: TweenComponent;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TweenComponent]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TweenComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call Tween.to', () => {
    spyOn(TweenMax, 'to');
    component.toggleDropdown();
    expect(TweenMax.to).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, then feel free to edit this blitz, otherwise the issue is in your code !

Comment: WHAT?! I literally just copied the style of the `it` and it worked?! Something must have been going wrong with how we were trying to create a spyObj before?

Comment: Do you know of a way in which I can check that the actual CSS values have changed? Everything i have thrown at that has also been a failure. In this context I would be writing: `expect(component.myElement.nativeElement.style.height).toBe('50px');`

Comment: Well you need to use `spyOn(TweenMax, 'to').and.callThrough();`, otherwise the function isn't called (replaced by a spy). Also, consider using `fixture.detectChanges();` if the test still fails !

Comment: Seems so simple once you find out how to do it! Although I can't get the CSS height test to work given your advice :-( - I have saved the Stackblitz with the issue in.

Comment: That's because `element.style.height` refers to the `style="height: XXpx"` attribute of your tag. To get the full height of an element, try `element.getBoundingClientRect()` and see what's in it (sorry I'm on phone I can't do it myself !)

Comment: Ah, that is a useful attribute to know for future! However, it can only seem to find the height to be = 34, and never 376 despite me running it after the call to expand the div :-/ -  I have changed the stackblitz to reflect this

Comment: Well I don't know your dependency enough to help you after that. Be sure to call detect changes and to call through your spies !

Comment: But again, as we have had this discussion in other topics, you should expect your function to have been called with given parameters instead of checking if the function worked : by doing so, you abstract the behavior of a dependency, making your unit test a real unit test (instead of a unit test relying on a second unit)